# post on Facebook page big photo

Tags: facebook, sdk, photo

I have read quite a few posts about posting photos on FB (fan)page but none really answer my question.
I am using a correct call to the FB SDK to post on [my page](http://www.facebook.com/PaulGodard.SoulPhotography) as you see the last post where there is a thumbnail photo and a few pieces of text including a link.

> $attachment = array('access_token' => $FB_Token, 'message' => $FB_AppMsg,'name' => $FB_AppTitle,'link' => $FB_AppURL,'description' => $FB_AppResume),'picture'=> $FB_AppImage,
>   'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $FB_AppActionName,'link' => $FB_AppActionLink)));
>   $status = $facebook->api("/".$FB_PageName."/feed", "POST", $attachment);

Instead of a thumbnail image, I want an image of the width of 1 or 2 column (as you will see down the timeline), and a text message that can include a link to my blog on my website.
How can I achieve this **easily** ?

Comment: Please help... I need to implement this on my site.

Comment: I tried :$attachment = array('access_token' => $FB_Access_Token, 'source' => '@'.$FB_AppImage, 'message' => $FB_AppMsg); ... but it does not work!

Comment: I got it : $args = array('message' => 'text here', 'access_token' => 'xxx'); $args[basename($img)] = '@'.realpath($img); $photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'POST', $args);

Comment: Now I want to add a link within the message field.  How can I do that?